# How should I replace a reference to an IP in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

I am trying to install ELK in Docker Swarm mode.

Then, I need to tell filebeat to send logs to logstash.

Here is my filebeat config file:

```
#=========================== Filebeat prospectors =============================
## Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
## you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
## Below are the prospector specific configurations.
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
{% for log in in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.logs | default([]) %}
    - {{ log }}
{% endfor %}

#================================ Outputs =====================================
# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["{{ in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.output.logstash }}:{{ in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.output.port}}"]
```

but `in_filebeat_dict.filebeat.output.logstash` is an IP and in Swarm mode, Swarm will not decide where to install containers, so I'm a bit stuck here...

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swarm mode discovery works over ne `--name` parameter. So when you deploy logstash with `--name logstash` other services can access it by calling the name `logstash`. But remember, they need to be in the same network which is not ingress. Create a new overlay network if you haven't done it yet and assign all services to that.

Comment: yes, I have them in the same network. When I create a service in a stack, services names are prefixed by the stak name, so the service name is: logstash_logstash. logstash and logstas_stash seam to both work. Do you know why ?

Comment: You mean the prefix which is added by the sack? I guess it's just the definition. And you can easily make green blue deployments with this. just deploy everything again with a new stack name so that the new stack doesn't interference with the former stack. when everything runs fine, just update you reverse proxy config and your fine. updated without downtime